# Prove that $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+x^2}$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$) is differentiable and check whether $g'(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

The function $g(x)$ is a function series, so it is differentiable when $g'(x)$ converges uniformly. So I should just check uniform convergence of $g'(x)$ by using the Weierstrass M-test:
$$g'(x) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+x^2}\right)' = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^n+x^2}\right)',$$
then
$$\left|-\frac{2x}{(2^n+x^2)^2}\right| = \frac{2|x|}{(2^n+x^2)^2} \leq \frac{2|x|}{(2^n)^2} =  \frac{2|x|}{4^n}.$$
But now I can't find a sequence that is bigger than $\frac{2|x|}{4^n}$ to use.

For checking whether function $g'(x)$ is continuous or not, I think I will use the same argument: If $g''(x)$ converges uniformly, then $g'(x)$ is differentiable $\Longrightarrow$ continuous.

Am I solving this problem in a correct way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $$|g'_n(x)|=\left|-\frac{2x}{(2^n+x^2)^2}\right| = \frac{2|x|}{2^n+x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n+x^2}.$$
Since
$$ \frac{2|x|}{2^n+x^2}\le\frac{1+x^2}{2^n+x^2}\le1, \frac{1}{2^n+x^2}\le\frac1{2^n}$$
you have
$$|g'_n(x)|=\left|-\frac{2x}{(2^n+x^2)^2}\right| = \frac{2|x|}{2^n+x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2^n+x^2}\le\frac1{2^n}.$$
Now you can conclude that $\sum g_n'(x)$ converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that the function $g(x)$is differentiable infinitely many times. It is convenient to consider  $$h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over 2^n+x},\quad x>-1$$ since the differentation of each term is much simpler and $g(x)=h(x^2).$ It suffices to show that $h$ is differentiable infinitely many times. However
$$a_n(x):-{d^k\over dx^k}(2^n+x)^{-1}=(-1)^k {k!\over (2^n+x)^{k+1}}$$  Hence $|a_n(x)|\le k!\,2^{-(k+1)n},$ which implies that the series $$(-1)^kk!\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over (2^n+x)^{k+1}}$$ is uniformly convergent for $x\ge -1/2.$ Thus $h\in C^\infty[0,\infty).$